# Ratio with Dependent Gaussian Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, gaussian

I have a problem which comes down to the following ratio of weighted Gaussian random variables $u_i$,

$$\mathbf{y} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{x}_i u_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N  u_i},$$

where $\mathbf{x_i} \in \mathbb{R}^D$ are vectors and $u_i$ are i.i.d. Gaussian.

I have been trying to figure out the distribution of $\mathbf{y}$, and even for the special case $N=2$

$$\mathbf{y} = \frac{\mathbf{x}_1 u_1 + \mathbf{x}_2 u_2}{u_1 + u_2},$$

I am not quite sure how to approach it. The challenge is that the numerator and denominator are not independent.

Any pointers are very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even if $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb R^{\color{red}{1}}$ (and $N = 2$), the problem is still not easy and perhaps there is no closed form for the distribution of $\mathbf{y}$

Comment: yes, that's what I am also fearing. Simulating it, the distribution looks quite like a Gaussian but with some outliers (because it may happen that one divides by something close to zero). 

At one point I thought the solution might be found using the Couchy distribution, which could describe ($u_1$/($u_1$+$u_2$)). But then one gets a sum of couchy distributed variables, which are again not independent